# Rotating the first frame of a gif using Python Pillow turns the image black

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

So I have this code:

```py
url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2c/Rotating_earth_%28large%29.gif"
first_frame = Image.open(requests.get(url, stream=True).raw)
first_frame.save('first_frame.png', quality=95)
```

This code saves the first frame of a GIF into a .png, which I am able to see by opening it, however if then I try to do the following:

```py
first_frame = first_frame.rotate(90) # rotate the picture
first_frame.save('first_frame.png', quality=95) # save the rotated picture
```

it makes the picture all black. This is very weird, the exact code works perfectly images, and the first frame of the given gif is saved as a .png, and therefore it should work with no complications, but it does not.

I have also tried:

```py
# with this I also get the first frame successfully but after trying to rotate it, it transforms into a black image
first_frame = Image.open(BytesIO(requests.get(url,stream=True).content))
first_frame.save('first_frame.png', quality=95)
```

```py
# same result, I get the first frame, then try to rotate it and it transforms into a black image
with open('first_frame.gif', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(requests.get(url).content)
first_frame = Image.open('first_frame.gif')
first_frame.save('first_frame.png', 'png', optimize=True, quality=70)
```

Any help? I also tried to rotate the whole GIF, but that didn't work.

EDIT:
I do in fact get the first frame of the GIF, and I can open it and it does act like an image, however when  trying to rotate it, it returns a black image.

EDIT 2:
Seems like I had to change the color mode of the picture to RGB in order to get the right output.

Comment: I ran the first 2 code blocks (your initial attempt) on repl.it and they work perfectly for me. Please verify the same and let me know.

Comment: They do, in fact, I haven't tried on repl.it or any other source, but in my main project I need to display it using Django, so the problem intervenes here, now:  `return FileResponse(open('first_frame.png', 'rb'))`. Seems like it has something to do with the bytes and stuff. Thank you for pointing out, I am getting closer and closer to a solution.

Comment: should we close this question ? the code (first two blocks) works fine with me and no black picture at all ? so its either reformulate the question or .. ?

Comment: Image.open('first_frame.png', 'rb') throughs a: raise ValueError(f"bad mode {repr(mode)}")

ValueError: bad mode 'rb'

Comment: Yes, close the question, I got the code to work and even wrote a fix that worked for me. It was working well however the rotate function was setting the color mode to L, making it all black. It is weird, but setting the image mode to RGB fixed it.